# Escribir respuestas con notas al pie de página

Tags: discusión

Alguna vez leí o escuché que las notas al pie de página estaban fuera de uso.

Será que soy de la vieja escuela, pero a mi me gusta usar notas al pie de página algunas veces en respuestas, por ejemplo, para explicar cosas que no son necesariamente parte de la respuesta pero que pueden ser orientadoras o formativas, o ayudar al OP a implementar mejores prácticas ([aquí un ejemplo reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214997/29967)).

El estilo que suelo usar es muy simple:

- Poner el número entre etiquetas `<sup>` y `</sup>`, algo así: <sup>1</sup>
- Poner al final de la respuesta una raya continua con `***`
- Escribir en negritas la palabra **Notas:** y dejar un espacio
- Para las notas, poner de nuevo cada número rodeado de `<sup></sup>`, y el contenido de la nota ponerlo rodeado de `<sub></sub>`

Aquí un ejemplo:

---

> Texto de una respuesta cualquiera donde quiero indicar algo al pie de
>   página <sup>1</sup> que puede ser interesante, a manera de
>   orientación.
>
> Más texto de la respuesta ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
>   magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
>   ullamco laboris <sup>2</sup> nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
>   dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
>   laborum.

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1</sup><sub>Nota al pie uno... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ...</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Nota 2, en *laboris*... nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</sub>

---

**¿Piensan ustedes que las notas al pie de página deberían evitarse en Stackoverflow, porque este sitio no es Wikipedia, porque están fuera de uso o por cualquier otro motivo?**

**¿Usan ustedes notas al pie de página? Si las usan, ¿cuál su estilo?**

**¿Qué les parece mi estilo?**

Comment: A mí me parece perfecto. Condensa contenido interesante sin entorpecer la lectura de la respuesta en sí.

Comment: Personalmente me parece estupendo. Contribuye a la claridad de la respuesta aportando enlaces de apoyo adicional.

Comment: No creo que deban evitarse si aportan algo a la respuesta, y visto el ejemplo que has puesto me parece muy correcto el uso que has hecho de el.

Comment: Sería ideal para explicar ciertos puntos si no se comprenden.

Comment: A mi poner la nota encerrada en `<sub></sub>` me parece que dificulta la lectura, yo prefiero dejar el tamaño original y así [llevo tiempo haciéndolo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2742+tambi%C3%A9n+conocida+como+arreglo).